# How to prevent mouse icon to be changed?

Tags: c, gtk3

Is it possible to prevent mouse cursor icon to be changed above paned separator ? --> I want to disable the resizing function of paned object.

By the way, I have already find the way to response to resizing action by add "notify" event, likes this :

---

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static gboolean motion_notify_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event);
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *toplevel;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    toplevel = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    GtkWidget *hpaned = gtk_vpaned_new();
    GtkWidget *frame1 = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
    GtkWidget *frame2 = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
    gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(frame1), GTK_SHADOW_NONE);
    gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(frame2), GTK_SHADOW_NONE);
    gtk_paned_pack1(GTK_PANED(hpaned), frame1, FALSE, FALSE);
    gtk_paned_pack2(GTK_PANED(hpaned), frame2, TRUE, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(frame1, 50, 50);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(hpaned), "notify",  G_CALLBACK(motion_notify_event), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(toplevel), hpaned);
    gtk_widget_show_all(toplevel);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

static gboolean motion_notify_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event)
{
    gtk_paned_set_position(GTK_PANED(widget), 50);
    return TRUE;
}
```

[image: mouse icon is showing resizing]

Comment: Your code (last code chunk with `main`) does not seems to be some [MCVE] (so please improve it to make it one). Your `motion_notify_event` is not used from your `main` (or installed as a callback). Please **edit your question** to provide some [MCVE]

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch On the contrary, it already is.  As stated in the second paragraph of the OP's post, the first two code chunks are showing how he has been able to intercept motion events to presumably lock the window size, and are nothing directly to do with the code in the third chunk.  They are merely an example of work done to solve a somewhat related problem.  **As it stands**, that third chunk is a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am able to compile (in isolation) the last chunk with  `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-x11-3.0) -Og -g george.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-x11-3.0) -o george`. When I debug that with a breakpoint on `motion_notify_event`, that function is unknown and the breakpoint is never reached. So indeed the last chunk is an [MCVE] but it does not call (or link) the `motion_notify_event` of the first chunk

Comment: Now we have an [MCVE] and I upvoted the question. Thanks GeorgeS!

Comment: I upvoted but *please* indent your code properly!

Comment: [gdk_window_set_cursor?](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor) Also related [GtkPaned property "shrink"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPaned.html#GtkPaned--c-shrink)

Comment: In addition to David: Out of curiosity, I digged a bit into the source code [gtkpaned.c](https://code.woboq.org/gtk/gtk/gtk/gtkpaned.c.html#_GtkPanedPrivate) on woboq and found a `GdkWindow *handle` in `_GtkPanedPrivate`. I assume if the cursor of this window would be changed this might solve your issue. Btw. is there any chance using these new CSS features? (When I developed in GTK+ 2 these were not yet available - so no experience...)

Comment: Does it have to be GtkPaned? Why not use [GtkBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkBox.html) if you don't want to resize it?

Comment: @pan-mroku, The GtkBox is not easy to adjust the size of childs I want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Glade under CentOS 7, Widget flags property "Sensitive" is your answer.

Please try gtk_widget_set_sensitive(your widget, FALSE).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPo4Y.png)

Comment: If I set the paned sesitive to FALSE, it will also disable the response of the button on the paned.

Comment: I want to put some buttons on the child of paned object.